# Jest Not Mocking Anything?

Tags: jestjs

Here is an actual application running Jest 12.1.1:

**main.js**

```
console.log("Main log");
```

**__tests__/main.spec.js**

```
describe("thing",function(){
  it('should',function(){
    require('./../main.js')
  })
})`
```

When you run, `jest`,
It outputs `main log`

Shouldn't main.js be mocked here? What am I missing?

Comment: @P-RAD With four underscores on each side? I don't exactly think so. Is there a link to the spec for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the Module Ignore patterns.

I had `express` in my ignore patterns, and my project was in a folder called `express-rest-api`